# Would kafka create a new follower if one of its replica is down to keep up with replication factor

Tags: bigdata, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Below is my partition information for the topic **xx_json_topic** .This is a Kafka cluster with three nodes .

All nodes up :

```
Topic: xx_json_topic    PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:2    Configs:
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2,1
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 3    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2,3
```

At this point..  if i bring down the node "node-1" ..It looks like below :

```
Topic: xx_json_topic    PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:2    Configs:
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
Topic: xx_json_topic    Partition: 3    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2,3
```

My question is ..if kafka knows that the node-1 is down and it needs to maintain the replication factor ,wouldn't it make node 3 a replica for partition-1 && node-2 a replica for partition-0  then make node-3 and node-2 part of their Isr ?

Or you think Kafka doesn't promise that... 
If replication factor is 2 ..It doesn't mean that data will be available in atleast 2 nodes at all time(---like consistency level in Cassandra) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that this is not the way replication factor is handled in Kafka. When you specify a replication factor of 2 for a topic, the partitions of that topic are created on 2 brokers (and the cluster controller attempts to spread them out over the cluster). At that time, one becomes the leader, and one becomes the follower. This is not a guarantee that there will always be two copies of the partitions, it only specifies that two replicas are created, and the brokers will notify you (via the underreplicated partitions count mbean) if all replicas do not exist.

Kafka does not perform any automatic repair of the cluster, with the exception that if you have multiple replicas for a partition, and the leader replica becomes unavailable, one of the followers will take over as leader. When that leader comes back, however, it will not resume leadership (it becomes a follower). In the same way, the cluster will not create new replicas. This can be a very resource-intensive operation, as a lot of data needs to be moved across the network to the new replica.

While there is an option to perform automatic leader rebalancing, there is no equivalent option to perform automatic replica creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I think this might explain what happened to me today. We have a 4 nodes Kafka and one of the topics had 4 partitions with replication factor 2 (two ISR). Then one node died (node failure) and when it comes back for some reason it was stuck and was always under replicated (could not rejoin as ISR). A few hours later a rolling restart was then carried out which has resulted a significant amount of message loss in one partition. Now my assumption is because the leader node got rebooted during the rolling restart, Kafka's default option is to choose an out of date replica...

Comment: ... continues from the last reply. The `choose out of date replica` option is mentioned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1028 which is available since 0.8 (default is favour availability). I guess the solution is to 1) Monitor if there's any constantly under replicated partitions and fix that stale node! 2) Do No.1 and up the replication factor to 3. Change Kafka to favour consistency is also an option but probably need to be careful with this one as it could mean Kafka stops accepting messages :( I'll also try this out to see if I can replicate the message loss again.

Comment: I also found reading the following articles helped me significantly on understanding exactly how replication works with Kafka. http://www.confluent.io/blog/hands-free-kafka-replication-a-lesson-in-operational-simplicity/
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#replication
Hope this can help the others having similar problems.